# List of major companies using Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

Outside the Backbone.js site itself (front page) and this page https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Projects-and-Companies-using-Backbone, I am trying to find a comprehensive list of compoanies using it.  I know Twitter uses it too I think.

Anyone know of where to find a list like this?  I've searched and no luck so far.

Answer (score 3):

There's a list on the backbone site:
http://backbonejs.org/#examples

Lots of duplicates with your list, obviously, but it does contain a few notable extra ones such as Soundcloud, Pitchfork, Pandora, Khan Academy, Foursquare and Linkedin Mobile.